# Image replacement with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of images on a page, and when the user clicks the image (a JPG) I want to replace that image with a corresponding animated GIF. The src of the GIF is contained in a data-gifsrc attribute.

I have trawled around for a jQuery function and I am having trouble putting anything meaningful together.

Has anyone written a function like this before?

Comment: You need to at least try something, and then post your attempt here.

Comment: I'll help you get started -> `$('img').on('click', function() { this.src = $(this).data('gifsrc'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4VUv/

HTML:

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <input type="image" class="image" src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg" data-gifsrc="tmapimage.img" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".image", function () {
    var gifsrc = $(this).data(gifsrc); //get the data-gifsrc value in variable
    $(this).attr("src", gifsrc); // replace the src attribute with gifsrc variable

});
```

Comment: DRY. `$(this)` is a surprisingly expensive operation, and you should not use it more than once for a given `this` value

Comment: Also, why require adding a class? `$(document).on("click","[data-gifsrc]",function() {this.src = this.getAttribute("data-gifsrc");})`...

Comment: well, you are right BUT adding a class is more meaningful and easy to find the element

Comment: Thanks for this. I would have posted something but my jQuery was really fragmented and tbh pretty rubbish. Embarrassingly so. I only use it once every few months so I always get in a pickle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for such a trivial task.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    var attr;
    if( e.target.nodeName == "IMG" && (attr = e.target.getAttribute("data-gifsrc")) {
        e.target.src = attr;
    }
},false);
```

If browser compatibility is an issue, use this:

```
function addEvent(element,event,callback) {
    if( element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(event,callback,false);
    else element.attachEvent("on"+event,function() {callback.call(element,window.event);});
}
addEvent(document.body,"click",function(e) {
    var tgt = e.srcElement || e.target, attr;
    if( tgt.nodeName == "IMG" && (attr = tgt.getAttribute("data-gifsrc")) {
        tgt.src = attr;
    }
});
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is *awesome*.